# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated Android Studio and SDK tools to the latest version and now I got this error. I have updated Google Services and firebase dependencies accordingly. I tried to clean and rebuild the project but the result is same.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException: element == null
```

Here is my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.crisser.beitnaonline"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
    force = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 
'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.appolica:interactive-info-window:v1.0.6'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Anyone knows why it does that? It worked just fine with 25.0.3.

Comment: delete your .gradle folder from the project and was able to rebuild it again. Make a backup, just in case.

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: oh yeah, if you have the same problem I forgot to add the actual dependency for glide above the annotationProcessor, so it was unknown for  Gradle, sorry for the late answer, but the question is kinda old :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't compile corresponding dependency with annotation

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
```

Add this to your gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, even though I solved the issue like 4 years ago, this might help people in the future

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through same issue. I just removed the dependency I added and my app began to work fine.

you should remove library one by one and build the application..